# SQL Query not accepting variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to pass a variable into a SQL update statement to update a table column. I run the following commands and do not receive any errors. However, the table column was not updated.

```
$SQLserver = 'servername'
$Database = 'databasename'

$variable = (Get-Content -path \\share\test\testfile.json | ConvertFrom-Json)

$vm = Invoke-SQLCMD -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $Database -Query "Update (tablename) set (columnname) = 1 where vmid IN ('$variable.attribute')"
```

I see that all the data is being passed into the variable. But, the update statement is not updating my column. Also, I do not receive any error messages when running my code.

Comment: Simple variables expand in  double quotes. To access properties of a variable, enclose in a subexpression `$()`. Check the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

you were too close, only "$" missing, here's the correct code

```
$SQLserver = 'servername'
$Database = 'databasename'

$variable = (Get-Content -path \\share\test\testfile.json | ConvertFrom-Json)

$vm = Invoke-SQLCMD -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $Database -   Query "Update $tablename set $columnname = 1 where vmid IN ('$variable.vmid')"
```

Comment: You should test before you post an answer. This is not a valid answer currently.